# Separating a text by a line in the same block with css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a line between text using css... but i don't know how to do it.

I am using bootstrap. So I have a block like

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
 <span> HELLO ------------------- 6/04/2019  </span>
 <p> Some text </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

i would like that all these dash would be a line that separate HELLO and the Date...

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `flex-box` to align items in the same parent.
I changed a little your HTML markup, look:

```css
.flex-paragraph {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.line-separator {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <p class="flex-paragraph">
      <span>HELLO</span>
      <span class="line-separator"></span>
      <span>6/04/2019</span>
    </p>
    <p> Some text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, thank you... but... how can i draw that line in the middle?

Comment: Just changing the value: `align-items: flex-end;` to `align-items: center;`